# Problem with running exe file from c#

Tags: c#, .net, exe

When I execute an exe file (PVFProject15.exe), it reads the data from an input file (inputFile.txt) and print the results in another file (outputFile.txt).  The exe file works well when I double click it;  It opens the console window which stays opened until the output file is created.  However, when I run (PVFProject15.exe) from c#,  the console window opens and closes very quickly and the output file is never created.

I would really appreciate your help since I have been working to fix this for a whole day and never found the answer.  Here is my code below.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
        Process runFortran = new Process();
        try
        {
            runFortran.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\temp\\trial\\PVFProject15.exe";
            runFortran.Start();
            runFortran.WaitForExit(); 
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Safaa

Comment: I've tried your code with notepad, and other console application's I've created, and it seems to work fine. Do you have the code for the PVFProject15.exe?

Comment: You didn't set StartInfo.WorkingDirectory to @"c:\temp\trial".  Lots of poorly written programs cannot survive that.

Answer (score 1):

Probably PVFProject15.exe needs current directory to be set to C:\temp\trial

Answer (score 0):

If `PVFProject15.exe` writes to file using relative path, look for `outputFile.txt` in directory  from which you start your main program-bootstrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet with same problem, when I try start some .exe and .hta from my C# based software.
I start to looking for solution and answer of Mike Mozhaev get to me right direction.
In your code you need to use: 
`StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Convert.ToString( System.IO.Directory.GetParent(appPath));`

So code have to be like this:

```
 if (File.Exists(appPath))
                {
                    Process runProcess = new Process();
                    runProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Convert.ToString( System.IO.Directory.GetParent(appPath));
                    runProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute= true;
                    runProcess.StartInfo.FileName = appPath;
                    runProcess.Start();

                }
```